# JQuery twentytwenty Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Pretty new to coding, can't get this plugin working. I know this will be a quick fix for more experienced peeps, but for me, it's driving me insane...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="event.move.jquery.json"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.event.move.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.twentytwenty.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twentytwenty.css">
        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                $("#container1").twentytwenty();
            });
        </script> 
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container1" class="twentytwenty-container">
            <img src="images/IMG001.jpg">
            <img src="images/IMG001_alt.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've downloaded and pasted the JS files exactly as they came online. The instructions at the plugin source page make it sound so simple, but I ain't got a clue what I'm doing wrong... All I have done is change the images. Any guidance would be much appreciated :)

Plugin Source: http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console? Hit F12 in Chrome, Firefox or IE and look for red stuff.

Comment: Yeah, a few... Main one is SyntaxError in event.move.jquery.json... has a green arrow pointing inbetween the : and " of this bit of code -  "name": "event.move" . Don't know what's supposed to be there though.

Comment: Looks like they're using jquery 1.10.1 in their examples, so you might try using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js instead of your script to get jquery-3.

Comment: Also, their examples don't include event.move.jquery.json either, so @Moustafa El-Sayed is probably right about moving that out of there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery 1.10.1 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting this line and try again

```
        <script src="event.move.jquery.json"></script>
```

Comment: Made no difference.